# Calculate typing speed of email addresses

Tags: javascript, typing, stopwatch

I need to calculate the typing speed of the user, the typing speed is calculated by inputting his email address.

The user will compete with other users who typed their email address. How I am doing it is I am getting the time taken to input their email address. e.g. 5 seconds

Then get the number of characters inputted e.g. 23 characters divide that by 5 (average word length)

Total Time / Total Words typed * 60 = Words per minute

The problem is that there is a discrepancy, if a user has a short email address e.g. me@me.com he will get 170 words per minute whilst if you have an average one like chrisemail@hotmail.com you will get 55 words per minute.

How can I find a way to standardize or add weight so that I can compare typing speed?

Comment: you wont get good data from the small sample size. The only appropriate measure would be characters/second, and even that would be easily skewed.

Comment: It would be so much simpler if you could just make the users you were comparing type the same thing.

Comment: Impossible (or impractical) to properly compensate for as you'd also have to account for things like repetition of close characters -- think about the difference between `googoo@googoogaga.net` and `wilfried@smithslaw.com` when typed by the same user.  Additionally, because of repetition, people tend to type their emails and common passwords at a much higher speed than other text.

Comment: I agree with all of you, it would be easier. My idea is to gamify a registration process where whilst registering you can compete for the fastest typer and win a prize. It would be brilliant if I could figure this out. I am not actually concerned about the accuracy of the data It's just a gamified way of registering.

Comment: @user991384 that makes sense to me.  How about logging their speed using your current method, then later run through your database and compare users to others who have passwords of the same length.  Whichever of these group winners was the highest above average for their group is your contest winner.

Comment: @DanielMendel so basically you are suggesting that I have several winners depending on the email size? mmm that would be one approach, although I'd prefer a structure where I can have one winner or at least the top 10. How the setup is right now the user enters his email address gets his wpm compares to the highest wpm in the database and if he is the fastest typer issues a message else it tells him his wpm and compares him to an animal in the animal kingdom e.g. snail if slow :) Is there a mathematical formula where I can add a weighting depending on the email length?

Comment: aaa ok Daniel I think I understood what you where saying The fastest typers from the different groups are calculated then the total is calculated and the average is calculated the highest one which is below average will be the winner. Ok will require some coding but do you think this will be indicative because how I am seeing it if someone took 3 seconds to type in his 6 character email address and for somebody else to type 23 characters took 10 seconds then the average would be 10 + 3 / 2 = 6.5 there is no way how the one who typed the longest email address to win. Am i right?

Comment: @user991384 Not quite, what I was suggesting is that you only compare the speed of `me@me.com` with other users who have 9 character long email addresses.  You compare the speed of `williamvandervettering@mysteriousauthors.com` with other 44 character long email addresses and so on.  Once you've ranked everybody among their peers, you take the winner who was the furthest *above their group average*.  That person was stastically the fastest compared to other users with similar length email addresses.

Comment: aaa ic, that would work! thanks but how would you go about displaying their typing speed you still show their wpm (words per minute) or else you would show them in seconds how long they took and display a message "you are the fastest typer" or in case that they are not "im sorry there is someone faster than you" ?

Answer (score 3):

You standardize by having the users type the same input.  This is especially important when you're having them enter very small amounts of data.  Consider the following:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla fermentum felis nec quam accumsan venenatis porta ligula vehicula. Praesent vitae sapien vitae velit tempor luctus eget a enim. Praesent eros metus, commodo id adipiscing vitae, congue eu tellus. Nullam feugiat, massa at adipiscing congue, tellus dui mollis nibh, id convallis metus libero sed libero. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nunc vitae congue eros. Sed non fringilla purus. Quisque lectus leo, lacinia vitae elementum at, laoreet eget leo. Integer sit amet orci tellus. Sed diam metus, elementum id varius at, iaculis sit amet eros.

This took me approximately 28 words per minute (which is much slower than my normal typing speed).  It's a significant amount of text, but even more importantly is the fact that it's not normally typed text.  It's not in my native language, so I had to slowly analyze each word.  It's not composed of things I type very often.  And so on.

> I

This took me approximately 600 words per minute (though it was difficult to estimate, so there's a significant margin of error there).  A personal best to say the least.

Why did these results vary so significantly?  Because I was typing very different things.  When you add another variable to this equation (multiple people), you get even more variation.

You need to standardize the test.  When educational institutions test their students, they generally have those students perform identical, if not at least functionally equivalent, tasks.  This helps eliminate variables so that the only variable is the one being tested... the person.

Comment: Agreed I guess in my case I will need to find another way to gamify the registration process. I wasn't looking after accuracy, but I need a fair structure where the output will not vary a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try something along these lines:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea id="email_add"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Done" id="done"/>

        <script>
            var doneButton = document.getElementById('done');
            var emailArea = document.getElementById('email_add');
            var lengthOfEmail = 0;
            var time_start = 0;
            var time_end = 0;



            emailArea.onkeyup = function() {
                lengthOfEmail++;
                if(lengthOfEmail == 1) time_start = new Date();
                else time_end = new Date().getTime() - time_start;
            }

            doneButton.onclick = function() {
                alert("Email Length: " + lengthOfEmail);
                alert("Time: " + time_end + " milliseconds.");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, you're going to want to adjust the email address length to accommodate for the shift that's pressed when the '@' symbol is entered.  But this should help you get the time, along with a way of verifying that they're not just copying and pasting.

Comment: That is exactly what I did! :) What I did was for each keypress I increment a count and then compare the count to the length of the value in the textbox. I did so to avoid the user from using the autocomplete. Although this doesn't solve the problem, you cannot compare typing speed of someone who typed me@me.com with someone whose email address is chris@hotmail.com which is longer. That is my problem I need to find a way to standardise the email length even if they input emails with different length

Comment: You know, you could set something up for registration.  You could have a Captcha box, and then another standardized box for them to fill out.  The second box will be their baseline to compare against the email address typing speed.  If you go that route, you'd need to access some server side data to pull their information from to get the baseline when they registered for the site.  OR that could be part of the gaming experience, to be used for other applications too.

Comment: I don't think I explained the scenario well sry for that. What I have is a launch page where the user can register to be notified when the product is launched. I decided to gamify the registration process to increase conversion rates :) So basically you have an input field to enter the email address and the users compete on beating the fastest typing speed which will be displayed